# Google Cloud MessagingでSERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE?

Tags: java, android, gcm

AndroidのGCMを使いプッシュ通知を実装したいと考えていますが、表題のErrorで止まっております。

止まってる箇所は

```
private void registerInBackground() {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> execute = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                String regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_ID);
                Log.d("MESSAGE", regid);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            Log.d("MESSAGE", msg);
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

のString regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_ID);のところです。

Google Could Platformでプロジェクトを作り、GCMを有効にしたのですが、うまくいかずに困っております

ひとつ疑問なのですが、

```
String regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_ID);
```

こちらのプロジェクトIDですが、
https://console.developers.google.com/project/forward-theorem-XXX
の
プロジェクト ID: forward-theorem-XXX プロジェクト番号: 99XXXXXXXXXX
の99で始まる数字の方であってますか？

いろいろ調べてみてはいるものの、これという回答が見つかってないので、質問させていただきました。
関係ありそうなコードは晒しておきます。

```
package shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    private final String PROJECT_ID = "99XXXXXXXXXXX";

    /** Google Cloud Messagingオブジェクト */
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

    ViewPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    /** コンテキスト */
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCustomPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        registerInBackground();
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> execute = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    String regid = gcm.register("990089809533");
                    Log.d("MESSAGE", regid);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                Log.d("MESSAGE", msg);
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm.GcmIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="shiratsu.ch.co.jp.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

使用前に端末側で`GCM`が使えるか確認しましょう。多分ですが使用されている実機が`Google Play Services`を利用できない状況になっていると思われます。

https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/google/gcm/client.html
に、確認するためのコードが提示されているので下記に引用しておきます。

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```